# Auto-refresh files when using tramp

Tags: files, tramp, auto-revert-mode

I am viewing remote log files using tramp mode in emacs. Is there a way to get tramp to auto-refresh  these buffers when they change remotely? If this is not possible, is there a way to reload a buffer every time it is opened?

I have tried to set `(global-auto-revert-mode t)`, but this does not work.

---

Edit: Just found out that [this is intended behaviour](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Reverting.html):

> You can also tell Emacs to revert buffers periodically. To do this for
>   a specific buffer, enable the minor mode Auto-Revert mode by typing
>   M-x auto-revert-mode. This automatically reverts the current buffer
>   every five seconds; you can change the interval through the variable
>   auto-revert-interval. To do the same for all file buffers, type M-x
>   global-auto-revert-mode to enable Global Auto-Revert mode. These minor
>   modes do not check or revert remote files, because that is usually too
>   slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a customizable variable named auto-revert-remote-files, which does what you want.

Comment: This gives me: Symbol's function definition is void: auto-revert-remote-files.

Comment: This flag has been introduced with Emacs 24.4, so it might be, that your Emacs version is too old.

Comment: M-x emacs-version says: GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) of 2014-10-24 on LEG570

Comment: `M-x customize-variable RET auto-revert-remote-files RET`

Comment: That's really strange, because I use the same version. Please check, if there is a file autorevert.el.gz in in your lisp folder of the emacs distribution. If you find the variable name in there, you probably don't haven't loaded it at the time you try to customize the variable.

Comment: Works, thanks! Don't know what was wrong.